# Loading data from text file to mysql database by eliminating duplicates

Tags: mysql

I want to load the data from text file to database, if data already exists i need to escape that data while loading.

I am using below query to load the data from text file to mysql data base.

"Load data infile 'F:/wbrdata.txt' into table wbrdatatable
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by ""
lines terminated by '\r\n'
Ignore 1 lines (channel, time, pulserate, dwellid, targetid);"

It is appending the data to existing table data. I want to avoid the common data which is already exists(duplicates) in table & file while loading to the database.

How can i achieve this?
thank you

regards
sankar

Comment: What program do you use to load textfile to mysql

Comment: In java i wrote program to execute above query.

Comment: I am using simple JDBC program to load excute this query      String str="Load data infile 'F://Hello.txt' into table newwbrtable fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by \"\" lines terminated by '\r\n' Ignore 1 lines (time, channel1,channel2);";
Class.forName(driverclass).newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user,password);
st = con.createStatement();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load text file into the temporary table (the same as target table), then remove duplicates from the temporary table and copy the rest to the target table.

---

Example (suppose that wbrdatatable_temp is a temporary table with all data from text file):

```
CREATE TABLE wbrdatatable(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO wbrdatatable VALUES 
  (1, '111'),
  (2, '222'),
  (3, '333'),
  (4, '444'),
  (5, '555');

CREATE TABLE wbrdatatable_temp(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO wbrdatatable_temp VALUES 
  (1, '111'),
  (2, '222'),
  (10, '100'), -- new record that should be added
  (11, '200'); -- new record that should be added

-- Copy only new records!
INSERT INTO wbrdatatable
SELECT t1.* FROM wbrdatatable_temp t1
  LEFT JOIN wbrdatatable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;

-- Test result
SELECT * FROM wbrdatatable;
+----+---------+
| id | column1 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 111     |
|  2 | 222     |
|  3 | 333     |
|  4 | 444     |
|  5 | 555     |
| 10 | 100     | -- only new record is added
| 11 | 200     | -- only new record is added
+----+---------+
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my Question. While loading data from text file to database, if the same data exists in table then i will skip that data and remaining i have to load to table.

Comment: I suggested you to load all data into another table, then delete duplicates and add records. You even can delete/add using one query, I will add an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is useful for me. But it is using additional memory for same data(temp table), won't it create any problem with huge database files? Before that, can't we use some sub query with some conditions along with my query(loading file into database) to escape existing data. Please don't mine for this type questions. thank you once again....

Comment: You also may make those fields unique. Then load data with IGNORE option, it automatically will skip all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Logic.

```
   1. Upload  Text File Data
   2. Check record using select statement on your database

    if(recordexist==true)
            save
    else
            not save
```

Regards

Comment: thank you for reply. You mean, after completion of loading data from file to database, i have to filter all duplicates, right? can't we eliminate duplicates while loading to database by using some sub query. If you know can send that syntax, please......